# GETH has only few peers

Tags: go-ethereum, peers

I start my geth node with the command:

```
geth --syncmode="light" --cache=4096 --http --http.port 8545 --http.corsdomain "*" --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --http.api "eth,web3,personal" --ws --ws.port 8546 --ws.origin "*" --ws.addr "0.0.0.0" --nat upnp console
```

And I get the following command prompt output:

[image]

I don't know why I have a maximum of 8 peers at time, with an average of 4/5. I tried disabling the machine's firewall and the peer count won't change, so it has nothing to do with that. I have port forwarded the required ports "30303 and 30301".

How can I increase the peer count? Thanks

Comment: Is your node behind a nat? In that case I'll forward p2p port 30303. Since light protocol isn't enabled by default there aren't many nodes available.

Comment: @Ismael I am not behind a nat!

Comment: There is an old page https://gist.github.com/rfikki/e2a8c47f4460668557b1e3ec8bae9c11 (see also its forks) but all of these peers are obsolete =(